# WeChat Social Login

Tags: authentication, oauth, wechat

I'm trying to integrate WeChat login with current system.

I own a **WeChat offical account** and already have **AppID** and **AppSecret**.

**Server Settings** enabled as well.

When I was tring to hit the QRcode scan url with my appid and my own server redirect url as parameter(example as below)

```
https://open.weixin.qq.com/connect/qrconnect?appid=wxbdc5610cc59c1631&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fpassport.yhd.com%2Fwechat%2Fcallback.do&response_type=code&scope=snsapi_login&state=3d6be0a4035d839573b04816624a415e#wechat_redirect
```

The browser threw me this error page
[image]

What I expect is something like this

[image]

**Question:**


1. Is it because of I didn't go through the wechat verification thus unable to obtain the user basic information?


2. How to get the wechat verification?

Comment: Maybe this question should be asked to their customer support? They have a link at the bottom of the page for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is it because of I didn't go through the wechat verification thus unable to obtain the user basic information?

   **Yes.** To integrate wechat login, your wechat official account must be verified *service account* (*subscribe account* is not supported, even it is verified). Please refer to [official document](https://mp.weixin.qq.com/wiki?t=resource/res_main&id=mp1433401084) for more information.
2. How to get the wechat verification?

   To get the wechat official account verified, you can follow the steps in the customer support [document](https://kf.qq.com/faq/120322fu63YV131031EZJJ77.html).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who stumbles upon this issue, this a redirect uri issue and weixin dashboard doesn't address it properly. First of all get a your application registered and approved from weixin (very painful and long process). Then in Admin center / application details of the registered application Authorization callback domain field should be just domain name. For example xyz.com is authorized domain then authorization callback domain should also be xyz.com without any URI, but when you are making the API call use your own encoded URI so redirect_uri = http%3A%2F%2Fxyz.com%2Fwechat%2Flogin

Answer (score 0):

1. Your Official Account must be a Service Account
2. In the Basic Configuration,you can add your sever's IP to the IP White List,so that you can get the `access_token` by your **AppID** and **AppSecret**.